# Count strings occurrence in a pandas column which is a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': {0: ['credits received', 'points'], 1: ['points']}})

                            names
0  ['credits received', 'points']
1                      ['points']
```

And also a list which looks like:

```
lst = ['credits received', 'points', 'rewards']
```

What I need is the count of any of the list items found in that dafarame column (maybe as a dictionary):

```
count_dict = {'credits received': 1, 'points': 2, 'rewards': 0}
```

What I am doing right now is converting the dataframe column to a list and then iterate through the list to find count of those strings but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way. Is there an alternative to what I am doing?

Comment: Please post the code you're using; we'll start from there.  I expect that a vectorized `map` will be the best way to obtain the target list you need, but I don't know what that might replace in your implementation.

Comment: Have you created the list that contains all the values from rows already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) over `axis=1` and [`sum()`](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&sxsrf=ACYBGNSDKXb3aAlxCKy6K3Yj-DDKIhq6jg%3A1576259795642&ei=09DzXdbwJs-c4-EP2aqIgAc&q=df+sum&oq=df+sum&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l2j0l5.2144.7544..7788...8.2..3.135.2246.7j14....2..0....1..gws-wiz.....10..0i71j35i362i39j0i67j0i273j0i131j0i20i263j0i131i67.OdirW37ccsM&ved=0ahUKEwiWpsWpmbPmAhVPzjgGHVkVAnAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) and [`series.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df['names'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies().reindex(columns=lst).sum().to_dict()
```

---

```
{'credits received': 1.0, 'points': 2.0, 'rewards': 0.0}
```